# SQL Select Converting to ASCII/varchar from Hex

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data stored in a column in my SQL Server table like the following:

```
0x003600380032003200330031002D003400
```

I know the output for this should be:

```
682231-4
```

Can someone help me with the SQL code for the conversion?

Something like:

```
 select converttochar (0x003600380032003200330031002D003400)
```

Returns: 682231-4

I'm not sure if I am looking at hex or binary conversion or what....

Comment: Microsoft SQL 2016

Comment: Try this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/132996/convert-hexadecimal-to-varchar

Comment: The problem  is that this data isn't ASCII - The `0x00` is a null character that is interpreted as a string terminator. This is why you are seeing blank strings. Maybe SQL Fiddle strips this out. But the data isn't a valid SQL Server nvarchar encoding either . All the byte pairs need to be reversed `0x0036` would need to be `0x3600` to be interpreted as `6`. If all the characters are from the ASCII set then could just do a replace of `0x00` to strip it out (using a binary collate clause)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is difficult to see what the exact encoding issue is based on the sample data.

I imagine Larnu is correct and this is just UCS-2 encoded data that for some reason has had a leading null byte added.

Another interpretation is that this is UCS-2 encoded data encoded with a different endianess - so each double byte needs to be reversed (though then there is still a surplus null byte at the end).

As long as each alternate byte is `0x00` it doesn't much matter which case is correct. To strip out the null bytes and cast to varchar you can also use

```
SELECT REPLACE(0x003600380032003200330031002D003400, 0x00, '' COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin)
```

For the limited character set shown in the question these will all have the same effect. If the raw data can have non ASCII characters this approach will likely fall down.

Comment: This is perfectly simple.  Yes, all the characters will be ASCII just like my very limited example.  The community here continues to amaze me.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

This actually looks like you have an `nvarchar` with a leading `00` at the start. This is messy, but would work:

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(30),CONVERT(varbinary(60),STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(60), 0x003600380032003200330031002D003400,1),3,2,''),1));
```

This strips out the leading `00` characters, making the value `0x3600380032003200330031002D003400`, which *is* the `nvarchar` value for `N'682231-4'`.

It strips the value out by converting the `varbinary` to a `varchar` but using the style code `1`, this means you have a `varchar` with the value `'0x3600380032003200330031002D003400'`; allowing you to perform string manipulations. Then I use `STUFF` to remove the character and `CONVERT` with style code `1` to make it a `varbinary` again.

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dcd098739fbc72b7577036040eb5391b)

Alternatively, you could remove all the null character tuples and convert. This looks way messier as you can't just blanket replace `'00'` (or rather I don't feel it's "safe" to), so I put the characters into their tuples, and rebuild:

```
DECLARE @YourBinary varbinary(60) = 0x003600380032003200330031002D003400;

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP(60) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3)
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(60),CONVERT(varbinary(60),(SELECT V.SS + ''
                                                  FROM Tally T
                                                       CROSS APPLY(VALUES(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(60),@YourBinary,1),(T.I*2)+1,2)))V(SS)
                                                  WHERE V.SS NOT IN ('00','')
                                                  FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','varchar(60)'),1));
```

This idea might be better though, *if* some of your values have a leading `00` and others don't. Of course, this solution also **assumes** the end value is a `varchar`, not an `nvarchar`.

Comment: `SELECT REPLACE(0x003600380032003200330031002D003400, 0x00, '' COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin)`

Comment: You should post that as an answer, @MartinSmith ;) Hadn't even occured to me to think about collations.

Comment: It is just a suggested simplification to yours not a new answer (in response to "you can't just blanket replace '00'")

Comment: Certainly easier for others to understand though, I still think it's a new answer, as even if the result is the same, the method is different; and it's good to see those as answers as well.

Comment: Ahh, it's because I'm going down the pessimistic route of the OP *may* have data like `0x003600300000003900`, @MartinSmith . They *probably* don't, but considering that the OP is treating their sample value as a `varchar` (not an `nvarchar`) *suggests* it can have many (sequential)  null characters. Call me a cynic. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(60), 0x003600380032003200330031002D003400);
```

#### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/68565)

Comment: That seems to only work if the 00 are removed from the hex.  Otherwise, I get a blank result.  0x3638323233312D34

Comment: Interesting...  Running it on my SQL 2016 server produces different results.  Blank with the zeros and the expected result without...

Comment: I too have the problem that @PaulWetter describes, and i would actualyl expect that. `00` in a hex in a null character, so something like `003600380032` has 3 null characters in it. [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) won't even run the above; and I find it to be more reliable that SQL Fiddle at times.

Answer (score 1):

I had also same issue some ago and the used the below statement for convert and my problem resolved that time ..

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(60), 0x003600380032003200330031002D003400);
```

Please try to run this and see whether your problem is resolved or not?

Comment: I'm getting blank in result. How its working for you.